# Error 0xc0000006 when I start certain .exe

Tags: windows-7, runtime-error

I'm running on Windows 7. When I start .exe like a game I got this error message :

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000006). Click OK to close the application
```

And it's impossible to launch my application. But it's not for all my .exe.

e.g : I can launch chrome but I can't launch any games.

So I found a way to by pass this error. I created a file .bat. In this .bat I start 500 time an application who gives me this error by this command :

```
start C:\Path\To\My\Exe\example.exe
```

And randomly (I have to wait 5 minutes to 3 hours), sometimes my .exe works and I can launch my application. once I managed to launch one .exe on my computer I don't have this error anymore. I can launch all .exe on my computer.

But when I restart my computer I got this error again. I don't know why it works sometimes with my .bat and I don't know how to fix this error.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Most possibly you have some bad sectors on your disk or a RAM problem. This sounds me like a hardware problem rather than software problem. Because **Error 0xc0000006** is **STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR** which means program addressing the page which wasn't in the memory bacause of an I/O error (From TechNet):

```
//
// MessageId: STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR
//
// MessageText:
//
// The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The required data was not placed into memory because of an I/O error status of 0x%x.
// #define STATUS_IN_PAGE_ERROR             ((NTSTATUS)0xC0000006 L) // winnt
```

Try running

> **chkdsk /r /f /x**

on your system partition. See if it solves the problem. If not trying

> **sfc /scannow**

may help also. Maybe the bad sector corruption affected memory manager subsystem. SFC may fix that.

If all these doesn't fix the problem, you can try replacing the RAM module(s), one by one, if multiple.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to repair software side and take a look on my hardware next time. I hope that error isn't a hardware problem.

Comment: just in case other are looking at this, the command is sfc, not scf

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

A few months ago I faced the similar issue while starting games. Although the error code is different than mine, but the meaning of error is the same. I have tried this method to solve the issue you could try that too. First, you have to download this [software](http://www.mediafire.com/download/97erhoox4d3zabq/aio210.zip).

After that please extract the file and then open the folder. You will find another folder called **svcpack**

Open it and run **aio-runtime**

In the next window click on **Install** and wait for the installation to finish.

After that please restart your system.

And see if this works.

Basically what you are going to do is repairing your .net frameworks by correctly uninstalling and then reinstalling again.

Please note that using unverified software from file sharing site is not recommended as it may harm your system. Scan thoroughly before installing it to your system.

Comment: What is this software? Can you get it from a legitimate source? Telling people to download software from filesharing sources is suspicious at best. In the modern world of malware, phishing and trojaned software it runs contrary to popular knowledge to download software from unknown and potentially harmful sources.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I have tested the software with Bitdefender total security and I had no issue using the software. But you're right, what worked for me may not work for others. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this software at my next reboot.

Comment: It would also be good to say what the actual software is. A quick Google points me to a YouTube video which suggest that it is a collection of .net runtimes and other similar pieces. This would help because knowing what was in the file could allow more precise faultfinding if it does in fact fix the problem.

Comment: The following would appear to be a more reputable source, even though it is in German: https://www.computerbase.de/downloads/systemtools/all-in-one-runtimes/

Comment: Then this software is clean ?

Comment: From my experience, Yes.